# C# randomly choosing from Vector3s

Tags: c#, random, vector, unity-game-engine

This is my first time using C#. I am trying to assign transform.position randomly to either L1, L2, or L3. I have made an array of Vector3s which I then randomly choose 1 of the 3 Vectors3 from but that doesn't seem to work. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance. I am using MonoDevelop with Unity by the way.

```
L1=new Vector3(x,y,z);
L2=new Vector3(y,x,z);
L3=new Vector3(z,x,y);
Random rand=new Random();
Vector3[] randomVector3=new Vector3[]{L1,L2,L3};
transform.position=randomVector3[random.Next(0,2)}; //error here
```

//note: it does work if I use transform.position=L1 but like mentioned, I want it to be random.

Comment: I see `transform.position` is this Unity3D?

Comment: I believe so...if that's any different from regular Unity

Comment: I see a closing } where a ] should be. MonoDevelop is probably telling you the same thing. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity you can just use [**Random.Range**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

```
Vector3[] randomVector3 = {L1,L2,L3};

transform.position = randomVector3[Random.Range(0, 3)];
```

You need to use `0, 3` because the function is exclusive on the second parameter.

You could also be clever and use:

```
Random.Range(0, randomVector3.Length)
```